# Produce Markdown-file with linked citations using pandoc, without divs

Tags: markdown, pandoc, hugo, citations, pandoc-citeproc

Moin,

currently i create a Website for our institution using [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/). In some of the pages and posts i want to cite literature and link the short-reference with the full bibliography entry. The references are taken from a BibTex file. But i'm not satisfied with the results due to not-working `link-citations` and ugly `fenced_divs` of consecutive colons.

Because **Hugo** uses **Markdown** i took `pandoc` to create the posts/pages, and I use it regularly to convert **Latex** documents without significant problems. My workflow is the following: I write the post in a Markdown file with Markdown-citations (`@bibkey`) and afterwards parse this to Markdown again with the particular **pandoc-options**.

For example, I use a file like that:

```markdown
---
reference-section-title: Bib
---

# Heading

TextTextText. [@trouillot_silencing_the_past_2015] 

TextTextText. [@ashton_queens_egypt]
```

If I convert it with `pandoc -C -t markdown-citations --metadata link-citations test.md -o test2.md --bibliography=somebib.bib`, I receive the following:

```markdown
# Heading

TextTextText. ([Trouillot \[1995\]
2015](#ref-trouillot_silencing_the_past_2015))

TextTextText. ([Ashton 2003](#ref-ashton_queens_egypt))

# Bib {#bibliography .unnumbered}

::: {#refs .references .csl-bib-body .hanging-indent}
::: {#ref-ashton_queens_egypt .csl-entry}
Ashton, Sally-Ann. 2003. *The Last Queens of Egypt*. Harlow: Pearson.
:::

::: {#ref-trouillot_silencing_the_past_2015 .csl-entry}
Trouillot, Michel-Rolph. (1995) 2015. *Silencing the Past: Power and the
Production of History*. Beacon Press.
:::
:::
```

Unfortunately, the citiations-links are not working, wether if I upload it to my website, nor in my VS Code Editor. And the colons with their attributes look pretty ugly on the webpage.

So i tried `pandoc -C -t markdown_strict --metadata link-citations test.md -o test2.md --bibliography=somebib.bib`:

```markdown
# Heading

TextTextText. ([Trouillot \[1995\]
2015](#ref-trouillot_silencing_the_past_2015))

TextTextText. ([Ashton 2003](#ref-ashton_queens_egypt))

# Bib

Ashton, Sally-Ann. 2003. *The Last Queens of Egypt*. Harlow: Pearson.

Trouillot, Michel-Rolph. (1995) 2015. *Silencing the Past: Power and the
Production of History*. Beacon Press.
```

Now, the post itself looks fine, but the citiation-links still don't work.

I looked in the [pandoc documentation](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html) multiple times and also tried some things, like turning of **native_divs**: `-t markdown-citations-native_divs`. But couldn't find a solution so far.

Does someone who is much more familiar with **pandoc** and **markdown** have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: Try with `-t commonmark` or `-t gfm`.

Comment: Thanks @tarleb. Both options did it for the preview in VS Code and on Github/lab -- with working links and nice rendering. But on my test Hugo website the links from the inline-citations to the full references still don't work. But that may be more of a Hugo related problem, than one related to Pandoc...

Comment: `inline-citations` is not a standard Hugo feature. To mimic this feature, you could explore modifying your markdown file to define anchors in the references then modifying the render-link.html template https://gohugo.io/templates/render-hooks/ 
But it won't be easy to get the correct number for each citation.